# Image size problem for upload

Tags: php

I built a website which allow people to upload their photos using php, but the phots can't be successfully uploaded if the image size is too big, how can I avoid that problem, how can I make the people upload the image without the size limitation, could you show me some php code relevant to that if possible, thanks!

Comment: php always gives you a hint what has happened wrong. Turn on errors logging (if it hasn't been done yet) and read it.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible with `.htaccess`. You'll need to add the following lines to your file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
</IfModule>
```

Although it's probably better to increase the script execution time (so it doesn't time out waiting for the upload) and the maximum POST size, thus:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
    php_value post_max_size 20M
    php_value max_execution_time 120
</IfModule>
```

This sets the maximum execution time to two minutes, which is a very long amount of time, however this is just an example.

---

#### PHP solution (won't work - see comments)

First, turn on error checking; this will let you know *what's* happened and *where* by putting this at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

---

You'll need to change the `upload_max_filesize` and the `post_max_size` declarations in your `php.ini` (assuming you're using Apache).

Find a lines that look similar to this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
post_max_size = 8M
```

And change it to something like:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

This sets the upload limit to 20MB (which is rather large, I must say). If you're on shared hosting, it's very unlikely they'll allow you to edit `php.ini`. In this case, you can use [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) like such:

```
string ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');
string ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
```

This will set the upload limit to 20MB, or whatever you want to set it to.

*(Thank you to @Phil in the comments)* Do note that `upload_max_filesize` must be *less than or equal to* `post_max_size`.

Comment: Don't forget `post_max_size` which must be equal to or larger than `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: where should I put this in my php code, I tried to upload a 4MB picture and used the above code, but still not working, why?

Comment: @Jam: you cannot change the ini variables from within the PHP script that handles the upload - by the time the script is started, PHP's already aborted the upload and the ini_set will never get a chance to work. it HAS to be done at the .ini (or .htaccess) level.

Comment: I need an simple example, can you show me how it exactly works in ini or hataccess level, what I need to do, thanks!

Comment: @Marc Could you not set them in the script that outputs the upload form? Or are the values reset as soon as PHP is done executing?

Comment: @Tony I've come up with a .htaccess solution. Please let me/us know if it works.

Comment: where do I need to put it into?

Comment: @Tony Create a file called `.htaccess` in your document root and put the above lines into it.

Comment: @jam: post size limits in the upload form are irrelevant. There's no upload at that time and ini_set changes do not persist between script invocations